# How to spy on ejs render function with sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, ejs, sinon-chai

I want to check whether "res.render" is called with the correct arguments.

```
 it("Renders the page where a new user can be created", done => {
    const spy = sinon.spy(ejs, "render");
    chai
      .request(app)
      .get("/users/create")
      .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        spy.should.have.been.calledOnce;
        done();
      });
  });
```

Even thought the render function gets called, the test report tells me that render function is never called.

```
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected render to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times
```

How can I spy on a ejs render function that is called on the response object and assert whether it is called with the correct arguments?

EDIT:  Our project is using express-ejs-layouts to  render ejs files

Answer (score 0):

If you call `res.render()` using EJS, it's not `ejs.render()` that gets called but `ejs.renderFile()` ([source](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/720ab7f4d6c70972fd81da4c3327f675a02a79e8/lib/ejs.js#L911)).

Following the code path for that method, it never calls `ejs.render()`.

Spying on `ejs.renderFile()` is also not possible, because of how Sinon works (spying on `ejs.renderFile` replaces the *exported* reference to the `renderFile` method, but `ejs` uses the *internal* reference).

However, you can spy on `ejs.__express`, which is the function that Express will call for `res.render()`:

```
const spy = sinon.spy(ejs, "__express");
```

**EDIT**: I now realise that you want to make sure if `res.render()` is being called with the correct arguments, so it would make more sense to spy on *that* method:

```
const { response } = require('express');

...

const spy = sinon.spy(response, 'render');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error, the controller works fine when I test it manually, so I know the render functions gets called.

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have tested it. See my edit.

Comment: Did you get it to work for you?  I'm still getting the same error even with __express fix

Comment: Yeah, works for me, although I haven't tested with Mocha. I assume you require `app`? (**EDIT**: just tested with Mocha, also works fine)

Comment: I am requiring app.  Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try to figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Here's the code that I used to test: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/ac76dc5e6faf32345e9971ee4a367f71

Comment: Thanks. I also just realised that we are using a package called express-ejs-layouts.  That maybe why ejs function is not called